# Retrieving a user's recent information

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to get the equivalent of the user's recent information on the site? I can see it's possible with the API but would involve a lot of hammering of the API.

**Edit:** here's an example of my recent details (with some actual data): https://stackapps.com/users/recent/1174?StartDate=2010-05-30&EndDate=2010-05-30

Comment: What do you mean by "recent information"?

Comment: @Kevin: I think he means the stuff you would get in a user's RSS feed. Maybe recent points acquired as well.

Comment: @Kevin if you click on the email icon in the top bar, that recent link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently it *would* involve a lot of "hammering". I would love to see something like this get added too so that apps that need to "monitor" certain events can poll that method for changes.

As for implementation, the method could maybe return an array of `action`s and each would have a `type` member.

Comment: I reversed the -1. It would make a lot of sense to have this recent information as a call so the backend can be optimised for it, instead of a set of API searches

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [users/{id}/timeline](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/%7bid%7d/timeline) method quite similar?

You could get

```
"comments, questions, answers, badges, revisions, or accepted status"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of this information is exposed via the `/users/{id}/timeline` method.  The rest can be gleaned from the `/users/{id}/reputation` and `/users/{id}/mentioned` methods.

Is there something exposed via the "envelope" that you can't get at through the API?

Comment: Timeline doesn't show things that other users did in response to the {id} given.  In recents, you can see if a different user replied to one of your questions, voted your answer up, or replied to a comment.

Comment: @Jack M. - which would be why I pointed out /reputation and /mentioned, which do exactly that.  There is no one method that exposes notifications (currently) but the data is available.